# How To Plot Histogram of an Image?

Tags: java, swing, jai

How to plot and display Histogram of an Image ?If it can done using Java Advance Imaging API please suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link provides a tutorial to use the Java Advanced Imaging API http://www.raditha.com/java/image/ to do what you want. Personally I use the standard image API's to do this, create a BufferedImage from your image file and then use getRGB() on each pixel. From this you can get the individual red, green and blue values for each pixel. You can count the number of values, 0-255, storing them in an array like the bins of a histogram. I use this for internal processing and don't display the graph so unfortunately I can't help you with the displaying part.

Comment: OK but would you please post your code which shows how to get histogram data like how to use getRGB() and how to count no. of pixel?   Please post your part of code.

thanks in advance

Comment: Your image needs to be read in as a BufferedImage. Using 'image.getRGB(x,y)' you will get the pixel value as an int for that pixel, these can be passed to the Color class by 'Color pixel = new Color(image.getRGB(x,y));'. The color class has the methods 'getRed()' , 'getGreen()' , and 'getBlue()' . I use three arrays where each address is like the bin of a histogram, these arrays will be sized 256 and therefore you increment the index based on the value of each color, for instance if you find pixel(0,0) red's component is 64 you would increment redArray[64] by one.

Comment: here is how i load my image. please provide me next step to do it
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981328/plot-histogram-for-a-buffered-image-in-java]

Comment: The code on that question uses the Java Advanced Imaging API which I have no experience with so I cannot help you with that. Simply using 2D graphics, read the image in using a stream to build a BufferedImage, the use a nested for loop across the pixels to get the color and record them like I said in the first comment.